# A problem on continued fractions

Tags: solution-verification, continued-fractions

Find the value of $x$, if:

$$\large 1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+...}}}$$

My attempt:

Noting that:
$$\large x=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{x}}$$

$$x=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

question: Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Good job. =D

Comment: Well, you've left out a lot of algebra between the 2nd and 3rd equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your observation is valid *if* you know that [the continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) converges.  This is a "simple" continued fraction (technical term), so it's not hard [to show it converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Some_useful_theorems).  Check a few of the convergents and it will be apparent that these form a couple of sequences, depending on whether the last "denominator" is 1 or 2.  However there is a theory that shows the eventually "periodic" continued fractions (like this) are precisely [the quadratic irrationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction).  So your deduction can be made rigorous.

Answer (score 2):

If others would like to know how he arrived at that:

Like you stated:

$$\large x=1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{x}}$$

$$\large x= 1 + \frac{1}{\frac{2x+1}{x}}$$
$$\large x = 1 + \frac{x}{2x+1}$$
$$\large 2x^2 + x = 2x + 1 + x$$
$$\large 2x^2 - 2x - 1 =0$$
Quadratic Formula:
$$x = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{4 + 8}}{4}$$
$$x = \frac{2 \pm 2\sqrt{3}}{4}$$
$$x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Because $x = \frac{1 - \sqrt{3}}{2}$ is extraneous, our final solution is
$$x = \frac{1 + \sqrt{3}}{2}$$